# Missing modules / non existent files in React-Native/Expo project + AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo, dependencies, node-modules, asyncstorage

I'm currently making an expo/react-native project, which uses react navigation, redux and firebase, and other dependencies, at some point of developing there was a conflict with peer dependencies that broke my entire application and could no longer start due to this issue:

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

I tried removing, updating and downgrading some dependencies and installing them one by one but I have not found a clear root of this problem.
I use `npm install --legay-peer-deps` command as advised when I looked for answers before and it is still like this.

This is my current package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  },
```

To clarify I do NOT use the AsyncStorage in my application, at least not directly, it may be the case that some module uses it without my knowledge.

The second problem that arised is this:

> None of these files exist:
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid/index(.native|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.js|.js|.native.jsx|.jsx|.native.json|.json)
> 15 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
> 16 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
> 17 | import typeof DrawerLayoutAndroid from './Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid';

Then again I do not directly use this or have knowledge of any module using it.

If someone could give me a guidance to why this happens and how to solve it, it will be much appreciated.

This is the first mobile app I make and any insightful advice related to this issue or to react-native will be immensely helpful.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the firebase dependency for expo/react-native apps. How are you initializing firebase?